# On subgrid of jqGrid, the right border is not visible

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using the free jqGrid version 4.15.0, and I have a subgrid in the main grid and the right border of the subgrid is not visible.

jQuery version: 1.12.4
jQuery UI version: 1.11.4
fontawesome version: 4.7.0

See my fiddle or below code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/eL7h9e8z/

You'll need to click the + sign to show the subgrid.

```js
var maingriddata = [{
  Column1: "Test1",
  Column2: "Test1",
  ShowSubGrid: true
}, {
  Column1: "Test2",
  Column2: "Test2",
  ShowSubGrid: false
}];

var subgridData = [{
  SubCol1: 'SubCol1',
  SubCol2: 'SubCol2',
  SubCol3: 'SubCol3'
}, {
  SubCol1: 'SubCol11',
  SubCol2: 'SubCol22',
  SubCol3: 'SubCol33'
}];

$(function() {
  "use strict";
  var $grid = $("#policyGrid");

  $grid.jqGrid({
      datatype: "local",
      data: maingriddata,
      colNames: ["Column1", "Column2", "", ""],
      colModel: [{
        name: "Column1",
        width: 50
      }, {
        name: "Column2"
      }, {
        name: "viewsubgrid",
        align: "center",
        width: 21,
        formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
          if (rowObject.ShowSubGrid) {
            return "<span class='fa fa-fw fa-plus subgridIcon'></span>";
          } else {
            return "&nbsp;";
          }
        }
      }, {
        name: "ShowSubGrid",
        hidden: true
      }],
      cmTemplate: {
        sortable: false,
        resizable: false
      },
      iconSet: "fontAwesome",
      loadonce: true,
      altRows: true,
      caption: "",
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      shrinkToFit: true,
      autowidth: true,
      height: 380,
      pgbuttons: false,
      pgtext: null,
      toppager: false,
      pager: true,
      rownumbers: false,
      threeStateSort: false,
      subGrid: true,
      subGridOptions: {
        hasSubgrid: function(options) {
          return options.data.ShowSubGrid;
        },
        reloadOnExpand: false,
        openicon: "ui-helper-hidden"
      },
      subGridRowExpanded: function(subgridDivId, rowId) {
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
        subgrid_table_id = subgridDivId + "_t";
        pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
        var $table = $("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table>");
        $("#" + subgridDivId).append($table);
        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
          datatype: "local",
          data: subgridData,
          colNames: ['Sub Col 1', 'Sub Col 2', 'Sub Col 3'],
          colModel: [{
            name: "SubCol1",
            width: 100,
            resizable: false
          }, {
            name: "SubCol2"
          }, {
            name: "SubCol3"
          }, ],
          cmTemplate: {
            sortable: false
          },
          rowNum: 0,
          pgbuttons: false,
          pgtext: null,
          sortable: false,
          toppager: false,
          viewrecords: true,
          pager: true,
          rownumbers: false,
          height: '80px',
          autoresizeOnLoad: true,
          idPrefix: subgridDivId + "_" + rowId + "_",
          loadComplete: function(data) {
            $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid("setGridHeight", '100%');
          },
          beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
            return false;
          }
        }).unbind("contextmenu");
        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid', {
          add: false,
          edit: false,
          del: false,
          refresh: false,
          search: false
        });
      },
      beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
        var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target);
        if (iCol == $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "iColByName")['viewsubgrid']) {
          var $btn = $(e.target).closest("td").find('.subgridIcon');
          var $tr = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow");
          if ($tr.find(">td.sgcollapsed").length > 0) {
            $(this).jqGrid("expandSubGridRow", rowid);
            $btn.removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
          } else {
            $(this).jqGrid("collapseSubGridRow", rowid);
            $btn.removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }).jqGrid("navGrid", {
      add: false,
      edit: false,
      del: false,
      refresh: false,
      search: false
    })
    .jqGrid("hideCol", "subgrid")
    .unbind("contextmenu");
});
```

```css
.ui-helper-hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
$.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.0/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="pnlGrid" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;width:700px;">
  <table id="policyGrid">
  </table>
</div>
```

[Missing border image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWDF9.jpg):

[image]

I've noticed that if I reduce (manually) '.ui-jqgrid-hdiv','.ui-jqgrid-bdiv' & '.ui-jqgrid-pager' by 2px, the border is visible.

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: which border is not visible ?

Comment: @mrid, added an image, you can clearly see that the outermost border is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report and for the demo, which reproduces the problem!

The reason of the problem is the usage of wrong `box-sizing` on `.ui-jqgrid` (outer div of the grid) in case of grid as subgrid. The `box-sizing` of all jqGrid elements should be `border-box` with the only exception `.ui-jqgrid`, which should be `content-box`. One can fix the problem by adding the following additional CSS rules:

```css
.subgrid-data > .tablediv > .ui-jqgrid {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.subgrid-data > .tablediv > .ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The first rule reset `box-sizing` of `.ui-jqgrid` to `content-box` and the next one changes it back to `border-box` for children of `.ui-jqgrid-view`. I updated the main code of `ui.jqgrid.css` on [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) too (see [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/587867156a6eb1b154386fa8fb120a25133021b8)).

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/eL7h9e8z/2/ demonstrates working of the changes. I made some other small changes in your code to fix some minor problems.

Comment: it working fine now. Thank you. One more thing, can you either update the github front page to show what versions of jQuery & jQueryUI we can use. I think what I use is old, I got the versions from the zipped donwload of the release. Thanks.

Comment: @Bugzee: One can use any jQuery from 1.7.2 till the latest 3.2.1 and jQuery UI starting with 1.8.11 will the last 1.12.1. You should take in consideration, that some versions of jQuery UI required not so old versions of jQuery. It's recommended to use jQuery either the latest 1.11.x or 3.x.x.